# How to make a scrollable bucket_list using shiny and sortable

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, scrollbar

Assuming following app from [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/trying-to-use-input-text-to-subset-sortable-input/61612?u=barret).

How to

1. fix the hight of the container aka "bucket-mother" aka `rank_list_1` to a specific size (SOLVED using style i.e. `max-height: 700px`)
2. and more importantly, how to make the list items scrollable?

Thus, a scrollbar has to be appear on the right side of the container if the list of items is too long.
There is this Autoscroll function, but I have not figured out how to use it correctly:
https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable/tree/master/plugins/AutoScroll#options

Demo:
https://jsbin.com/dosilir/edit?js,output

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(".bucket-list-container {min-height: 350px;}"))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 12,
      #choose list of variable names to send to bucket list
      radioButtons(inputId="variableList",
                   label="Choose your variable list",
                   choices = c("names(mtcars)"="names(mtcars)","state.name"="state.name")),
      #input text to subset variable names
      textInput(
        inputId = "subsetChooseListText",
        label = "Input text to subset list of states to choose from",
        value = "c"
      ),
      div(
        # class value is current default class value for container
        class = "bucket-list-container default-sortable",
        "Drag the items in any desired bucket",
        div(
          # class value is current default class value for list
          class = "default-sortable bucket-list bucket-list-horizontal",
          # need to make sure the outer div size is respected
          # use the current default flex value
          uiOutput("selection_list", style="flex:1 0 200px;"),
          rank_list(
            text = "to here",
            labels = list(),
            input_id = "rank_list_2",
            options = sortable_options(group = "mygroup")
          ),
          rank_list(
            text = "and also here",
            labels = list(),
            input_id = "rank_list_3",
            options = sortable_options(group = "mygroup")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 12,
      tags$b("Result"),
      column(
        width = 12,
        
        tags$p("input$rank_list_1"),
        verbatimTextOutput("results_1"),
        
        tags$p("input$rank_list_2"),
        verbatimTextOutput("results_2"),
        
        tags$p("input$rank_list_3"),
        verbatimTextOutput("results_3")
        
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input,output) {
  
  #initialize reactive values
  varList <- reactive({
    req(input$variableList)
    if (input$variableList == "state.name") {
      state.name
    } else {
      paste0(rep(names(mtcars), 20),"_", 1:220)
    }
  })
  
  subsetChooseList <- reactive({
    items <- varList()
    pattern <- input$subsetChooseListText
    if (nchar(pattern) < 1) {
      return(items)
    }
    items[
      grepl(
        x = items,
        pattern = input$subsetChooseListText,
        ignore.case = TRUE
      )
    ]
  })
  
  output$selection_list <- renderUI({
    labels <- subsetChooseList()
    
    # remove already chosen items
    labels <- labels[!(
      labels %in% input$rank_list_2 |
        labels %in% input$rank_list_3
    )]
    rank_list(
      text = "Drag from here",
      labels = labels,
      input_id = "rank_list_1",
      options = sortable_options(group = "mygroup")
    )
  })
  
  #visual output for debugging
  output$results_1 <- renderPrint(input$rank_list_1)
  output$results_2 <- renderPrint(input$rank_list_2)
  output$results_3 <- renderPrint(input$rank_list_3)
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution. Taken from the bubblescoll demo: https://jsbin.com/kesewor/edit?html,css,js,output

The css `overflow-y: auto;` with a `height` is doing its job.

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)


ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 12,
      #choose list of variable names to send to bucket list
      radioButtons(inputId="variableList",
                   label="Choose your variable list",
                   choices = c("names(mtcars)"="names(mtcars)","state.name"="state.name")),
      #input text to subset variable names
      textInput(
        inputId = "subsetChooseListText",
        label = "Input text to subset list of states to choose from",
        value = "c"
      ),
      div(
        # class value is current default class value for container
        class = "bucket-list-container default-sortable",
        "Drag the items in any desired bucket",
        div(
          # class value is current default class value for list
          class = "default-sortable bucket-list bucket-list-horizontal",
          # need to make sure the outer div size is respected
          # use the current default flex value
          div(
            style = "
                     max-height: 250px;
                     overflow-y: auto;",
            uiOutput("selection_list", style="flex:1 0 200px;")),
          rank_list(
            text = "to here",
            labels = list(),
            input_id = "rank_list_2",
            options = sortable_options(group = "mygroup")
          ),
          rank_list(
            text = "and also here",
            labels = list(),
            input_id = "rank_list_3",
            options = sortable_options(group = "mygroup")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 12,
      tags$b("Result"),
      column(
        width = 12,
        
        tags$p("input$rank_list_1"),
        verbatimTextOutput("results_1"),
        
        tags$p("input$rank_list_2"),
        verbatimTextOutput("results_2"),
        
        tags$p("input$rank_list_3"),
        verbatimTextOutput("results_3")
        
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input,output) {
  
  #initialize reactive values
  varList <- reactive({
    req(input$variableList)
    if (input$variableList == "state.name") {
      state.name
    } else {
      paste0(rep(names(mtcars), 20),"_", 1:220)
    }
  })
  
  subsetChooseList <- reactive({
    items <- varList()
    pattern <- input$subsetChooseListText
    if (nchar(pattern) < 1) {
      return(items)
    }
    items[
      grepl(
        x = items,
        pattern = input$subsetChooseListText,
        ignore.case = TRUE
      )
    ]
  })
  
  output$selection_list <- renderUI({
    labels <- subsetChooseList()
    
    # remove already chosen items
    labels <- labels[!(
      labels %in% input$rank_list_2 |
        labels %in% input$rank_list_3
    )]
    rank_list(
      text = "Drag from here",
      labels = labels,
      input_id = "rank_list_1",
      options = sortable_options(group = "mygroup")
    )
  })
  
  #visual output for debugging
  output$results_1 <- renderPrint(input$rank_list_1)
  output$results_2 <- renderPrint(input$rank_list_2)
  output$results_3 <- renderPrint(input$rank_list_3)
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at your code. You would first have to wrap the content of the list with another div, afterwards, you would have to define its width and height either in percentages, or pixels, then set the overflow for the wrapper div, and the scrollbar should show up on the right side.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Good idea, but how? :)